# Incorrect animation when building and deploying game to Android device

Tags: android, animation, unity-game-engine

After I build and deploy my game to an Android device, my animation displays incorrectly. The image below demonstrates the issue.

[image]

I don't know how to fix this. What may be the cause of the problem, and how can I fix it?

p/s: I use unity 5.1.1f1 , Win 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your `Camera`'s  `Clear Flags` parameter to `Solid Color`